# PassportJS not returning data

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I am having a problem with PassportJS where no matter what I do I cannot get the different modules to return anything.

For example, when I'm using `passport-google-oath20` I have code like this

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: keys.google.clientID,
  clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect"
},
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(profile);
  }
));
```

going to the `passport.authenticate` route, it simply outputs

```
{}
```

I'm using the `google` strategy as an example but this is not working for any of my strategies.

I have double checked that the keys are all correct and that I have the correct permissions, but due to the fact that it does the same for all of them it seems like it is due to the specific project.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty object in `passport.authenticate` because you haven't called `cb` from function that is getting user information from google.

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(profile);
    cb(null, profile);
}
```

Without calling `cb`, `authentication` method will never be executed

Also, please check if you have set scope correctly.